# I am getting 0 on the console when i am running robot file. I need to get the sum that is 6 how to get that?

Tags: python, robotframework

```
def sum_all(*args):

    print(args)
    _sum_ = 0
    for num in args:
        _sum_ += num
    return _sum_
print(sum_all(1,2,3))
```

when i am running this am getting output as 6

Robot Framework code:

```
*** Settings ***

Library     ../Library/demo.py


*** Variables ***


*** Test Cases ***

TC1

    Print Summ

*** Keywords ***

Print Summ

    ${sum}      sum_all
    log to console  ${sum}
```

When i am running robot file am getting 0 please help me with this how to get 6 in console.

Comment: Please, edit your question, in its current form no one will look at it seriously. The title is a short summary of the problem you are trying to solve; the description is for the rest - "please look this examp" including. It should include the problem definition - what are you actually trying to achieve, the issue - what's giving you trouble, and preferably a sample (which you have, kudos). Like it is right now, it will only accumulate downvotes & probably be closed.

Comment: Apart from the "welcome to SO, we have expectations here" rant :), what's the issue? Looking at the code, you are calling the method - albeit with no arguments, so it should return a `0`, and that should be printed on the console. What's the problem?

Comment: I am getting 0 but i need to get sum on console that is 6 but why i am getting 0 please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method sums its arguments, but you are not passing any - thus it returns a 0. Pass numbers that'll return 6 when summed:

```
${sum}      sum_all    1    2    3
${sum}      sum_all    2    4
```

Comment: Hello sir, can we Extend the function in a way that it can do sum or multiplication , where you should be passing operator as a parameter to the function,also try to pass '+' by default

Comment: It can be done - create a second method, that will multiply its arguments. Now combine the 2 methods in one, where one of the parameters is the operation type; start with `if operation=='+':` execute the summing code, `else:` - the multiplication. And for the operation parameter to have a default value, it must be after the varargs, e.g. the method signature should be something like `my_method(*args, operation='+') `.